# html.document_fromstring with attribute error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and was trying to do a small project. I am doing web scraping for my project to start with and having a problem with the imported library. I am using pycharm in ios environment and it's actually working fine in Jupiter.

So, I have imported html module package to my project but `html.document_fromstring` is still not working. it says `AttributeError: module 'html' has no attribute 'document_fromstring'`

I have tried to see if I made any mistakes with typing or while importing but I don't see any problem.

```py
import html
import lxml
import requests
import string
import re
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree


page = requests.get('https://1000mostcommonwords.com/1000-most-common-english-words/')
tree = html.document_fromstring(page.content)


words = tree.xpath('//*[@id="post-192"]/div/table')

col = []
i = 0

for t in words[0]:
    i += 1
    name = t.text_content()
    col.append((name))

name.replace('\n','')
name = " ".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+",name))

list(name.split(" "))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/katyang/PycharmProjects/Hangman_game/venv/hangman_game.py", line 11, in <module>
    tree = html.document_fromstring(page.content)
AttributeError: module 'html' has no attribute 'document_fromstring'
```

so this is my error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import html like this,

```
from lxml import html
```

Now, you can use like this,

```
tree = html.document_fromstring(page.content)
```